# How to convert the $_POST array into the desired array in following scenario in an optimum and efficient way?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've got the following `$_POST` array after form submission and executing following line of code:

```
print_r($_POST); die;//Code to print the $_POST array

//Following is the output of above statement 
  Array
(
    [fileName] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8.png
            [1] => 2_OnClick_OK.jpg
        )

    [fileLink] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd
            [1] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ
        )

    [Submit] => Submit File
)
```

But actually I want a new array titled `$request_arr` which after executing `print_r($request_arr); die;` command should look like as follows:

```
Array
        (
            [8.png] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd
                )
            [2_OnClick_OK.jpg]
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ
                )   

        )
```

N.B.:- For demonstration purpose only I've taken two elements. In actual scenario there could be hundreds of such elements. So please consider an optimum and efficient way to get this output array.

Thanks in advance.

If you have any query regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know.

Comment: Then you should re-format the array so it suits your requirements. What have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want but I'm not sure why you would want that structure to your data unless you have something that is expecting that data format and you can't change it.

```
// Check that both array have same number of elements
if ( count($_POST[ 'fileName' ]) == count($_POST[ 'fileLink' ]) ) {

    foreach ( $_POST[ 'fileName' ] as $key => $fn ) {
        $request_arr[ $fn ][ 0 ] = $_POST[ 'fileLink' ][ $key ];
    }
} else {
    // You have bad data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not yet what I wanted your code produces following output array :
Array
(
    [8.png] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd
    [2_OnClick_OK.jpg] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ
)

Comment: I want array in following manner:
Array
        (
            [8.png] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd
                )
            [2_OnClick_OK.jpg]
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ
                )   

        )
The key with index 0 is missing. Can you please update your code accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to yours Problem would be the "array_combine" statement.

Useage/example:

```
$fname=array("a","b");
$age=array("35","37");
$c=array_combine($fname,$age);
print_r($c);
// Output would be " Array ( [a] => 35 [b] => 37 ) "
```

hope it helps